# How to add a loop inside a variable php

Tags: php, loops, oop, syntax

I have to use a foreach loop inside a variable in php but Im not sure of the right syntax. This is what Ive tried but it shows an error(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH))

```
 $doctor = foreach($doctor->find_all() as $d){
      echo '<td>'.$d->getName().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getEmail().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getPhone().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getGender().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getSpecialist().'</td>';
      echo '<td><a href="../doctor/updatedoc.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a></td>';
      echo  '<td><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
    };
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: "it shows an error" — Please read [ask]. **Tell us what the error says!**

Comment: The error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: You can not _"use a foreach loop inside a variable."_ I am assuming that you want what all those echo statements currently write directly to the output buffer, as content of your variable? Then you need to either use output buffering, or simply _append_ to the content of your variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign loop on variable or with the echo
instead you can direct save the data to variable inside the loop

```
$doctor = "";
foreach($doctor->find_all() as $d){
      $doctor .='<td>'.$d->getName().'</td>';
      $doctor .='<td>'.$d->getEmail().'</td>';
      $doctor .='<td>'.$d->getPhone().'</td>';
      $doctor .='<td>'.$d->getGender().'</td>';
      $doctor .='<td>'.$d->getSpecialist().'</td>';
      $doctor .='<td><a href="../doctor/updatedoc.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a></td>';
      $doctor .='<td><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `$doctor = foreach(...`

That's not correct PHP syntax.

It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve (aside from outputting some HTML), but start by removing the variable assignment:

```
foreach($doctor->find_all() as $d) {
      echo '<td>'.$d->getName().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getEmail().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getPhone().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getGender().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d->getSpecialist().'</td>';
      echo '<td><a href="../doctor/updatedoc.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a></td>';
      echo  '<td><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
};
```